# Set successCssClass and errorCssClass for all input by default

Tags: yii

I want set successCssClass and errorCssClass all form's inputs in Yii. How I can doing it.

Comment: This question isn't clear. Do you want to change the name of the css classes for success and error or do you want to set all the inputs to have success and/or error classes by default?

Comment: Why don't you focus on elaborating your question

Comment: I want to change the name of the classes for success and error, but for all inputs. Now I using bootstrap ui, and want all inputs' error/success classes being has-error and has-success.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap from yii booster?

Comment: are the views already generated ? what's the view structure etc ... I afraid you have to go through each view and change the classes . if you have installed bootstrap , it works with gii to generate you crud views .

Comment: Probably you have to create a class wich extends from `CActiveForm`, and apply the classes in there. The diffrent Bootstrap extensions are using the same approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the the defaults are defined in jquery active form plugin i.e `/framework/web/js/jquery.yiiactiveform.js` look at the end .

However,as @Michiel suggested, You can  extend [`CActiveForm`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#clientOptions-detail) sth like this:

```
MyActiveForm extends CActiveForm{

  public function error($model,$attribute,$htmlOptions=array(),$enableAjaxValidation=true,$enableClientValidation=true)
    {
        //my defaults

        $defaults=array('errorCssClass'=>'myErrorCss',
         'successCssClass'=>'mySuccessCss',
         'validatingCssClass'=>'myValidationCss');

        $htmlOptions=array_merge($defaults,$htmlOptions);

      return parent::error($model,$htmlOptions,$enableAjaxValidation,$enableClientValidation);

    }
}
```

And you have to use your new class e.g

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('MyActiveForm', array(
   ..
   ?>
```

I don't see a better way right now. Either you have extend `jquery.yiiactiveform` plugin or `CActiveForm` .